# Intel 7260 wifi interface disappeared

Tags: networking, intel-wireless

The wifi interface has disappeared after a recent upgrade (not 100% sure which one sorry - might have been the os upgrade to wiley but might have been later).  Enable/Disable Wifi option not available on network manager.

lspci:

```
 ...
 06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

i.e. Looks OK

rfkill list:

```
2: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

i.e. Wireless missing.

iwconfig:

```
eth2      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

i.e. Wireless missing.

lsmod | grep iw:

```
iwlmvm                294912  0
mac80211              733184  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              548864  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
```

i.e. Looks ok

sudo lshw -c network:

```
*-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   version: 6b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:35 memory:f7900000-f7901fff
...
```

i.e. Looks OK

Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it with this:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here:  Fixed it with this:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300362